# how to start process monitor in a paused state?

Tags: procmon

I have a slow PC and lots of programs are running, I just want to trace the activities of Microsoft word,Therefore, I need process monitor to start in a paused state to first configure it to monitor only Microsoft word. How can I start process monitor in a pause(not monitoring) state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I start process monitor in a pause(not monitoring) state?

Use the `/NoConnect` command line option.

> `/NoConnect`  Don't automatically begin collecting events at startup

[image]